# Different response when I fetching and crawling url(scrapy)

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape [the website](https://www.1mg.com/). When I use, Scrapy shell with chrome user agent, I get the response(html content) same as viewed in browser.
But when I crawl same link using Scrapy script with default user_agent, it shows different response with content I didn't need. But when I change the user_agent to same used in shell, it shows 404 error.
Please help me. I am really stuck on it.
I tried many user agents. I also changed concurrent requests, but nothing is working.

Comment: Provide code, items you need from page and output. also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I guess you are looking for wrong XML address.